# fs.readFileSync always returns empty string

Tags: javascript, node.js, file, io

I have a script that writes data from an API to some files.  I have an object the contains the file descriptors for each file:

```
var csvFds = {
    'file1' : null,
    'file2' : null,
    'file3' : null,
    'file4' : null
};

for (var file in csvFds) {

    var dirPath = __dirname + '/files/' + file;

    try {
        fs.statSync(dirPath);
    }
    catch (e) {
        mkdirp.sync(dirPath, {mode: 0755});
    }

    csvFds[file] = fs.openSync(dirPath + '/' + moment().format("YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss[Z]") + '.csv', 'a+');
}
```

Then I have some code that uses fs.write to write lines of csv to the file in batches.  This part is working fine.  I have well formed csv files.  Now I need to read the contents of the entire file as a string.  This is how I'm trying to do it:

```
fs.readFileSync(csvFds['file1']).toString();
```

But for some reason I am always getting an empty string.  I have confirmed that fs.readFileSync is in fact returning a Buffer by using console.log and dropping the toString() method.

I'm really stuck on this so any help will be greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance.  Here's some additional info regarding my node version and OS:

```
$ node -v
v6.2.3-pre

$ uname -a
Darwin i-2.local 14.5.0 Darwin Kernel Version 14.5.0: Thu Jun 16 19:58:21 PDT 2016; root:xnu-2782.50.4~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
```

Comment: if you provide encoding to `readFileSync` method you will get a string instead of a `Buffer`

Comment: I've just discovered that a file with `[]`, as in an empty array serialized, is read with readFileSync it returns an empty string and length=0. I've tried returning as buffer and inspecting, it's the same. on macOS + Node v16.16.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to call `readFileSync` like this `readFileSync(csvFds['file1'], 'utf-8')`. It ought to return a string. Or you can omit the argument and then provide the encoding when calling `toString` method e.g. `readFileSync(csvFds['file1']).toString('utf-8')`

Comment: Hey Michael.  I had actually tried both of these things previously and just did it again.  But I still get an empty string.  There must be some way to get information about the file descriptors or Buffers to debug this.  I'm about to try switching the node version.

Comment: are you sure your csvFds dictionary contains correct data? can you show what csvFds contains after for loop ends?

Comment: it is a wild guess but this piece of code `now.getTime()` seems a bit suspicious to me

Comment: Here's is what csvFds contains just before calling readFileSync:

    { file1: 13,
      file2: 14,
      file3: 15,
      file4: 16 }

My version of the code is actually using moment.js to format the date not now.getTime().  I think the file descriptors are fine after the initial loop because I am able to write multiple batches of data to these files without any issues.

Comment: It's a super simple csv file like this but it's a few thousand lines long each:     

    168722|admin   
    328701|developer   
    172090|mail   
    328702|team

Not sure why the line breaks don't work

Comment: it is really hard to say what is the problem since it works perfectly fine for me

Comment: I think the file descriptors are fine because initially I was getting an error readFileSync because the file was opened with the wrong flag (a instead of a+).

Comment: I know this is crazy.  Let me try running this on linux instead of mac real quick

Comment: Maybe it's trying to read from the end of the file instead of the beginning or something

Comment: can you edit your question and add the output of `tree` command inside `files`  directory?

Comment: I just switched to using file paths instead of file descriptors and now it's working.  Unbelievable.  I wish I knew why.

Comment: I just faced a similar problem and what happened with mine was that I was creating a file using the async function writeFile() just before I was trying to read it using the readFileSync(), and there was a timing issue there. The file wasn't done being generated before the sync function was trying to read it. If you're generating a file then trying to read it, they both need to be sync functions.

Answer (score 4):

For others who have the same problem.

For me, the only way to have a non-empty string was to use fs.readFile instead of fs.readFileSync.

I use a Mac and I was trying to read a file that node create itself. If I try to read another file it works.

```
fs.readFile(file, (err, data)=>{
    if(err){
        console.log(err)
        throw err
    }else{
        let file_content = data.toString('utf8')
        // your code here
    }
})
```

Comment: I have the same problem sometimes even with async fs.readFile().  The data is sometimes "" even though I can verify that the file  exists and has non-empty content by then doing a sync read in debugger.  This happens on Windows 10.

Comment: @Panu Logic are you reading a file that is used by another stream or program?

Comment: Could be used by the editor I'm editing it with. Not sure. But I found a get-around. If the content seems to be empty I do a sync-read in my callback function now and I get the  correct content always so far it seems

Comment: ho ok, interesting.

Comment: This solution works for me, same situation (files created with NodeJS 12) but I don't why it happens. Does somebody have a clue?